# Access `process.env` property when testing nuxt.js app with jest

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, babel-jest

I want to write unit tests for my **Nuxt.js** application with **Jest**. But some of my components use `process.env` property declared in the `nuxt.config.js` file. When I run my tests I received this error:

[image]

Test file example:

```
import Config from "../nuxt.config"
import { mount } from "@vue/test-utils"
import CleanMapButton from "../components/UI/buttons/CleanMapButton.vue"

beforeAll(() => {
  process.env = Config.env
})

describe("Clean map button tests", () => {
  it ('Always true test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true)
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2):

[Imports are hoisted](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_modules.html#_imports-are-hoisted) so the `import` statements all run before `process.env` is set in `beforeAll`.

If an `import`-ed module needs a global variable set then it must be set *before the test starts running* by setting it in a setup module and configuring `Jest` to run that setup module using something like [`setupFilesAfterEnv`](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/configuration#setupfilesafterenv-array).

On the other hand, calling `require` runs the code *at the time it is required* so the alternative is to refactor your test code to call `require('../components/UI/buttons/CleanMapButton.vue')` *after `beforeAll` sets `process.env`*.

Answer (score 1):

You can just set them in beforeAll

```
beforeAll(() => {
  process.env = Object.assign(process.env, { get_settings: 'get_settings' });
});
```

Comment: I have added my test file source. Looks like this error forced before `beforeAll` method call. I think when 3rd import executed.